# Simple logger class vsnprintf is crashing with read access violation

Tags: c++, crash, printf

While implementing a simple printf style logger I encountered a vsnprintf crash. This is how I call the logger utility:

```
LoggerUtil->LogInfo("Whatever info here %s", "just a test!");
```

It calls a function with a variable number of arguments. The idea is to add extra information to the format string so I need to change fmt:

```
std::string LoggerUtil::LogClientInfo(const char* fmt)
{
    return "Some info here %s";
}

void LoggerUtil::LogInfo(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    std::string formatStr = LogClientInfo(fmt); // returns "Some info here %s" just for testing altering the format string
    const char* format = formatStr.c_str(); // checked memory and its '\0' terminated string
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, format);
    Logger::InfoVA(format, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}

void Logger::InfoVA(const char* fmt, va_list arg_list)
{
    Log(Priority_Info, fmt, arg_list);
}

void Logger::Log(Priority priority, const char* fmt, va_list args)
{
    char str[MaxLogEntrySize];
    memset(str,0,MaxLogEntrySize*sizeof(char));
    vsnprintf(str,MaxLogEntrySize-1, fmt, args); // CRASH :(
    ...
}
```

Can't figure out the main problem, not tempering with fmt solves the problem but it's not an option:

```
void LoggerUtil::LogInfo(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, fmt);
    Logger::InfoVA(fmt, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't immediately see an issue. Use a memory instrumentation tool, like purify or valgrind, to search for memory corruption. Just because a C++ program crashes in one particular function doesn't mean that's where the bug is.

Comment: `va_start(arg_list, format);` I guess it should be `va_start(arg_list, fmt);` Unless you are trying to do something tricky that I couldn't get. But basically you are derouting the `va_start` elsewhere, ==> UB. I did not post this as an answer as I am not sure that it fixes all possible issues in your code.

Comment: Since you're using `C++` there are far better ways to implement variable number of arguments, such as using [variable argument templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).  Then you don't get into this mess with va_start, va_arg, etc.  See the sample code at the link.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Remy's answer solved my problem for now, but I will rewrite the code based on the example you've sent, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `LogClientInfo()` to create a new format string, you are then passing the wrong input value to the second parameter to `va_start()`.  You are passing your local `format` variable, but you need to pass the `fmt` argument of `LogInfo()` instead.  Just because you are using a different format string when calling `Logger::InfoVA()` does not change where the input format values are stored.  `va_start()` configures the `va_list` to point at the next function argument relative to the specified argument, and in this case that needs to be the `fmt` function argument, not the local `format` variable:

```
void LoggerUtil::LogInfo(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    std::string formatStr = LogClientInfo(fmt);
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, fmt); // <-- use fmt here !
    Logger::InfoVA(formatStr.c_str(), arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}
```

Comment: I'm very grateful to you, changing va_start(arg_list, format); to va_start(arg_list, fmt); solved my problem. Thank you very much! Anyway I'm using C++14 so I will rewrite everything with variadic templates. Don't want to shoot myself in the foot with these counter intuitive va_list's again.